# SVN post commit hook won't execute telnet

Tags: svn, telnet, post-commit-hook

I have a SVN repo served by Apache over DAV.

I've created a post-commit hook that I want to open a telnet session to a server.

When I execute the commands from the command prompt, it works fine.

But when I execute it with the hook, it fails, saying that it doesn't have permissions to execute.

My script is simple:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 REPOS="$1"
 REV="$2"

 echo -e symeon\\nfrobnitz\\n.say \#foo easitag $REV $(svnlook author $REPOS -r $REV)    $(svnlook changed $REPOS -r $REV): $(svnlook log $REPOS -r $REV) | telnet server 8080
```

The hook is running on a RedHat Enterprise Linux machine.  I'm assuming it's executing as the apache user.

Anyone know why?

Comment: in the cli, `sudo su www-data` and try again

Comment: that user doesn't exist...

Comment: find the hanme of the apache user. May be apache, httpd, look at your process list / your apache configuration and find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on a rather obscure forum:

The apache user is disallowed to make http connections by default.  To enable this, do the following from root:

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

that was found on 
http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/64806-solved-could-not-connect-to-server-permission-denied/

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

1. The user account under which Apache is running (assuming that you're serving the repository with Apache) must have permission to do everything your script is attempting to do.
2. Hook scripts execute in an empty environment - no environment variables are set, not even `$PATH`. So those binaries you're attempting to execute (`svnlook` & `telnet`) aren't found. You need to specify the full path to those, or set a `$PATH` in your script.

Comment: 1. yes, this is correct.  But what rights?  That's really more the question.

2. Yes, i changed the script to a full path and still no dice.